# Updating one column with the value from another, based on another common column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large (3 million rows) table of transactional data, which can be simplified thus:

```
ID  File        DOB
--------------------------
1   File1       01/01/1900
2   File1       03/10/1978
3   File1       03/10/1978
4   File2       15/07/1997
5   File2       01/01/1900
6   File2       15/07/1997
```

In some cases there is no date. I would like to update the date field so it is the same as the other records for a file which has a date. So record 1's DOB would become 03/10/1978, because records 2 and 3 for that file have that date. Likewise record 5 would become 15/07/1997.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic in choosing the date? What if the same file appears with several different dates? Which is to be used for the update, anche which rows are to be updated? Is 01/01/1900 your null date value? Do you want to update only the rows that have a date of 01/01/1900?

Comment: 01/01/1900 is the null date value, yes.

I basically want to update the DOB column to the MAX(DOB) of the other records associated with that file. The most important thing is that the DOB is the same across all records associated with a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your table is called "Files", then this will work:

```
UPDATE f1 SET f1.DOB=f2.MaxDOB
  FROM files f1
  JOIN (SELECT File, MAX(DOB) AS MaxDOB FROM files GROUP BY File) f2 ON
    f2.File=f1.File;
```

As far as performance is concerned, it probably won't get much more efficient than this, but you do need to insure there is an index on the (File, DOB) column set. 3 million records is a lot and this query will also update records that do not need it, but filtering those out would require a much more complex join. Anyway... you better check the query plan.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Whole table dealt with in just over 90 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about most efficient way, but i can think of one solution...create a temp table with following query. Though i am not sure about exact keywords of sqlserver 2008, but this might work or you may need to change key word like to_date and its format.

create table new_table as (
 select file,min(DOB) as default_date, max(DOB) as fixed_date from three_million_table group by file having min(dob)= to_Date('01/01/1900','dd/mm/yyyy') )

so your new table will have 
column headers: file, default_date,fixed_date

values:    File1, 01/01/1900, 03/10/1978

Now it may not be wise to run update on three_million_table, but if you think it is ok then:

update T1
SET T1.DOB = T2.fixed_date
FROM three_million_table T1
INNER JOIN new_table T2
    ON T1.file = T2.file

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help... having 3 million records will surely take it toll to update the table by scanning each record

```
;WITH testCTE ([name],dobir,number)
     AS (SELECT [File],DOB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [FILE],DOB
      ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNumber                                    
         FROM   test)
UPDATE TEST
SET DOB = tcte.dobir
FROM testCTE as tcte
LEFT JOIN TEST t on tcte.name = t.[FILE]
WHERE tcte.number > 1 and [FILE] = tcte.[name]
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56c7c/5)